# Server framework for rich Dojo app?

Tags: javascript, ajax, frameworks, dojo

I've been working with web2py recently, and found it very nice to use for building RESTful web apps. However I've decided to extend my JavaScript skills a bit and tackle a more 'modern', rich, asynchronous client-side JS application. Something like Gmail, in the sense that it loads the UI up-front and then only talks to the server to keep the data in sync.

I'd like to use Dojo (used Dojo and jQuery in the past, and prefer Dojo for its structure) for the client-side stuff, but what should I use on the server side? What's the best way to get Dojo's data stores talking to a standard MySQL database? I sense that something like web2py, as simple as it is, would be overkill when it really just needs to handle AJAX DB requests. I can imagine that if Dojo could talk directly to the DB a server-side framework might not be necessary at all.

There are a few questions like "what is the best framework", whether JS or server, but I guess I'm wondering what role the server-side framework plays at all in an app like Gmail, and what is the most suitable framework for such minimal logic processing?

Comment: Remember in a web app the server side is really the most important, especially when security is concerned.  A hacker can completely by-pass your front-end code and talk to the back-end directly.  Therefore, you should start by designing a robust back-end which authenticates each request.  When you do that, it is never really *simple*.  I've seen that a REST service appears to be quite popular these days as back-end.  Once you get your back-end designed, you then write your Dojo front-end. In web apps, you develop in reverse order as a desktop self-contained app.

Comment: Something like a REST service was what I was thinking, but it would really just pass each request on to the DB. But of course you're right about security and control over those requests. I think I'll stick with web2py on GAE for now, though have been considering PHP frameworks for greater deployability. Cheers.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

When it comes to RIAs (Rich Internet Applications), the server needs to be just as robust and full featured as any other web application. The biggest difference is that the rendering of templates is outsourced to clients via javascript. So the short answer is, it doesn't matter. Just use whatever server side framework you feel most comfortable with.

Comment: Fair enough. With web2py for instance there's basically a template for every page, and there can be many pages. Could you basically just have the same setup but async functions rather than standard requests in the controller, and only a single template (maybe layout.html including some hunk of JS)? Seems logical enough.

Comment: I'm not familiar enough with web2py to say, but it sounds like you are on the right track.